# Make UIPickerView width fill the view

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I'm new to iOS developement and I'm stuck with a graphical problem:
I created a UIPickerView that appear above a google maps view. I would like to have the picker view width match the main view width.
Currently, the picker is always taking 3/4 of the view and is locate on the top left angle:

[image: the picker is not center and does not fill the view]

I try to do that:

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, widthForComponent component: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return self.view.bounds.width
}
```

But here is the result:
[image: The text inside picker is center but the picker does not fill the view]

And here is what I would like to have:
[image: My goal]
Any idea? Is it possible to set this in the storyboard and not in swift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not the width of the components, self.view.bounds.width already fixed that, you have a layout issue.

Check your auto layout constraints for the picker view, you may have a fixed value width or height constraint if you automatically set the constraints using Xcode.

If you added the pickerView programmatically check that your frame has the same width as the view, or that the constraints are correct (see Sharat's answer)

Edit: code to programmatically set pickerView width -

```
//call this in viewDidLoad
func resizePickerViewToScreenWidth(){
     let oldFrame = airspacePicker.frame
     var newFrame = oldFrame
     newFrame.size.width = view.frame.size.width
     airspacePicker.frame = newFrame
}
```

Edit 2: code to programmatically create the pickerView

```
var airspacePicker: UIPickerView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    createPickerView()
}

func createPickerView() {
    airspacePicker = UIPickerView(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 220.0)))
    airspacePicker.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    airspacePicker.autoresizingMask = .FlexibleWidth
    view.addSubview(airspacePicker)
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but where is the auto layout constraint? I check everywhere, I don't have a fixed value other than 600 which correspond to the max width.
The width anf height are set to "any" for the storyboard.

Comment: would you mind taking a snapshot of your constraints? They are open on this image i found http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-s_SrqWAcaGY/VYFr-I3IHuI/AAAAAAAAJlY/iyRa6qch1ME/s1600/view1e_all_constraints.tiff

Comment: also I think the 600 max width constraint is the main offender as it looks like you are in landscape mode, so the view width would be higher than that more than likely

Comment: The snapshot are in portrait but the application can be rotate in landscape, so I can't hard code width, right?
Here is two snapshot for the 3 constraint: 0 on left, 0 on right and pischer.top=layout.bottom
http://hpics.li/c585a84
http://hpics.li/4abcfd9

Comment: Ah, can you send me a picture of the tab just to the right of that one, I'm not sure your constraints are set!

Comment: Is that what you want to see?
http://hpics.li/4850246
I also made a video: http://teiki.fr/pickerview_1080p.mov

Comment: Hmm, so does the pickerView have the wrong width in both portrait and landscape or just in landscape?

Comment: By the way your pickerView is already constrained to the main view not the scroll view so you don't have to worry about that, in you picture you can see on the left that the pickerView is within 'view' (the main view)

Comment: I tell you what, I don't like doing things half auto layout half programmatic but I'll give you some code that should fix this. Just a second

Comment: Ok no problem, try the code I put in my answer, hopefully that will fix it

Comment: :/ No it doesn't.
I'm sure auto layout and size classes is causing it but I don't understand how.

Comment: Hmm, in that case try going the wholly programmatic route. Instantiating it in viewDidLoad etc.

Comment: also if you are using size classes, its worth double checking that all the constraints you've set in each size class are correct.

Comment: BTW, I put a pontbreak on the first line of your code.
view.frame.size.width = 414
and picker.frame.width = 600

Thank a lot for the help, I going to analyze in depth if I found smth

Comment: no problem! by the way I'm going to add some code to create the pickerView completely programmatically that works for me. hope that will help/at least reveal if it's autoLayout thats the problem.

Comment: youhou!! Doing it programmatically works!!
So I don't know why it doesn't work with storyboard but at least I can move on. Thank you, you rock!

Comment: no problem at all! Glad it helped, problems that don't seem like they should be problems are the most irritating haha

Answer (score 2):

You can create the constraints for uipickerview. select the picker view and set the following constrains. You can set the constrains in the storyboard.

Trailing space:0
Leading Space :0
Botton Space:0

https://www.raywenderlich.com/115444/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-2-constraints

Comment: I tried to add the constraints from the pin button to the uipickerview. It doesn't change anything

Comment: Set the constrains corresponding to the main view. First click the picker view and click the pin button and remove the checkmark in Constrains to Margin and set constrains for three sides as Zero.(don't set constraint depend on top)

Comment: This should be easy but I'm certainly do something wrong.
Here is some snapshot where I did what you said and it doesn't work:
http://hpics.li/c585a84
http://hpics.li/4abcfd9

Comment: No need to set the top constraint. First you want to drag a picker view into the view controller. and arrange to the bottom of the screen and set only three side constrains. No need to set the constraint on the top.
just check this link: http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=782840ScreenShot20160406at70633pm.png

Comment: Actually I want it to be display on top of the view.
Maybe there is a conflict with the map under because I can't display the picker at the bottom of the view even with the constraint set like on the screenshot

Comment: Ok. then do the same thing. Only set three constraints except bottom. Set constraints on top,left and right.

Comment: It's what I do :/
Is it normal that I have to do: 

    self.view.addSubview(airspacePicker)

inside func viewDidLoad()

I'm going to make a video of it

Comment: Ok so here is a video, thank you a lot for helping me.
I create the picker has you said and the result is same (just forgot to put background in white)
http://teiki.fr/pickerview_1080p.mov

Comment: Hi, I think the uipickerview constraints are set according tho the map view. Because map view is also a scroll view so this is show like this. so set pickerview constraint according to main view.

Comment: I don't see where I can choose to wich view I can set pickerview's constraints.
According to this screenshto, constraint are made between pickerview and superview, is this ok?:
http://hpics.li/4850246

Comment: set the view like this. http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=453144ScreenShot20160407at64706pm.png

Comment: I also do the same project I got the view correctly. http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=979835ScreenShot20160407at65411pm.png

Comment: Currently the mapview is add in the code with : self.view = self.mapView.
Maybe having the two view (map and picker) inside the main view would have avoid some conflict.
I use @OlivierWilkinson solution, adding programmatically the picker works too.
Thanks a lot for the help!!

Comment: Ok.  @Teiki. In may ways you can set that. thats ways also good. anyway you got the solution. I am happy.